# Node.js use setInterval & clearInterval on a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, twitch

Hello is there a way to call a function with setInterval and clear the interval later?

Example: When I write in a chat !start the interval function should start with a interval. And when I write !stop in the chat the function with the interval on it should stop.

This is my function:

```
function abb(channel){
    console.log('Auto-Ban-Bot Timer running...')
    getChannelViewers(channel.replace('#','')).then(
        promise => {
            var vierwernames = promise.chatters.viewers;
            vierwernames.forEach(element => {
                checkFriendlyBots(element)
            });
        }
    );
}
```

I've tried many things but only got the !start command working, not the !stop command.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `clearInterval()` method does. It clears a timer set with the `setInterval()` method.

Check out this example:

```js
const interval = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
let i = 0;

function myTimer() {
  console.log(i++);
  if (i === 5){
    stop();
  }
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```